# What is the right syntax of groovy/gradle for file collection filter and iteration?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

What is the right syntax of groovy/gradle for:

```
zipTree("/path/foo.jar")
   .include("**/*.xml, **/*.html")
   .eachWithIndex { file, index ->
   }
```

?

Comment: What's wrong with one you shared?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
zipTree('whatever.jar')
    .matching { include '**/*.MF' }
    .each { println it }
```

Comment: "it" is a file. Is there a way to get the entry name in the jar? not absolute path in file system. thanks.

Comment: @Sunnyday, entry day? What do you mean? It it's an instance of `File` - you invoke `getName` always.